# Kivy : How to use on_key_down and on_key_up keyboard event in Tree View?

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

I am using `python-2.7` and `kivy-1.10.0`.
When i click on `name` TextInput then Tree View shows. 
I want the label to be selected with the `up` and `down` keys, and when the `enter` key is pressed the text is copied the selected text is copied to the initial form as it is currently done when you click on the item

## test.py

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.treeview import TreeView, TreeViewLabel, TreeViewNode
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
Window.size = (500, 200)


def populate_tree_view(tree_view, parent, node):
    if parent is None:
        tree_node = tree_view.add_node(TreeViewLabel(text=node['node_id'],
                                                     is_open=True))
    else:
        tree_node = tree_view.add_node(TreeViewLabel(text=node['node_id'],
                                                     is_open=True), parent)

    for child_node in node['children']:
        populate_tree_view(tree_view, tree_node, child_node)


tree = []
rows = [(1, 'test1', 11), (2, 'test2', 2), (3, 'test3', 3)]
for r in rows:
    tree.append({'node_id': r[1], 'children': []})



class TreeViewLabel(Label, TreeViewNode):
    pass


class TreeviewGroup(Popup):
    treeview = ObjectProperty(None)
    tv = ObjectProperty(None)
    #ti = ObjectProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TreeviewGroup, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.tv = TreeView(root_options=dict(text=""),
                       hide_root=False,
                       indent_level=4)
        for branch in tree:
            populate_tree_view(self.tv, None, branch)
        self.remove_widgets()
        self.treeview.add_widget(self.tv)

    def remove_widgets(self):
        for child in [child for child in self.treeview.children]:
            self.treeview.remove_widget(child)

    def select_node(self, node):
        '''Select a node in the tree.
                '''
        if node.no_selection:
            return
        if self._selected_node:
            self._selected_node.is_selected = False
        node.is_selected = True
        self._selected_node = node
        print(node)

class GroupScreen(Screen):
    name = ObjectProperty(None)
    popup = ObjectProperty(None)

    def display_groups(self, instance):
        if len(instance.text) > 0:
            if self.popup is None:
                self.popup = TreeviewGroup()
            #self.popup.filter(instance.text)
            self.popup.open()


    def select_node(self, node):
        '''Select a node in the tree.
                '''
        if node.no_selection:
            return
        if self._selected_node:
            self._selected_node.is_selected = False
        node.is_selected = True
        self._selected_node = node
        print(node)


class Group(App):
    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_file('test.kv')
        return self.root


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Group().run()
```

## test.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<TreeViewLabel>:
    on_touch_down:
        app.root.name.text = self.text
        app.root.popup.dismiss()

<TreeviewGroup>:
    id: treeview
    treeview: treeview
    title: "Select"
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 400, 200
    auto_dismiss: False

    BoxLayout
        orientation: "vertical"
        #TextInput:
            #id: ti
            #size_hint_y: .1
            #on_text: root.filter(self.text)
        BoxLayout:
            id: treeview
        Button:
            size_hint: 1, 0.1
            text: "Close"
            on_release: root.dismiss()


<CustomLabel@Label>:
    text_size: self.size
    valign: "middle"
    padding_x: 5

<SingleLineTextInput@TextInput>:
    multiline: False

<GreenButton@Button>:
    background_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.parent.height * 0.150

GroupScreen:
    name: name
    test:test

    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        padding : 30,30
        spacing: 10, 10
        row_default_height: '40dp'

        CustomLabel:
            text: 'Code'

        SingleLineTextInput:
            id: test
            multiline: False
            on_text_validate: name.focus = True


        CustomLabel:
            text: 'Name'

        SingleLineTextInput:
            id: name
            text:' '
            multiline: False
            on_focus: root.display_groups(self)



        GreenButton:
            text: 'Ok'

        GreenButton:
            text: 'Cancel'
            on_press: app.stop()
```

Comment: @eyllanesc sorry for inconvenience. Traverse up,down using keyboard

Comment: @eyllanesc thank you.Yes,exactly i want to do that.

Comment: You can monitor the key events with `on_keyboard_down` [event](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.core.window.html). Also try this stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47212144/scrolling-and-focus-with-arrow-keys)

Comment: @eyllanesc really thanks.I updated question.

Comment: @eyllanesc I am just trying it.

Comment: @macsontaylor You should not edit your question with the proposed solution, since that would not be a question, it would be an answer.

Comment: @macsontaylor 
It is not a issue, it is another requirement that looks a lot but is not the same, please create another question and I will be happy to try to help you.

Comment: @macsontaylor Your question clearly talks about selection with the keyboard, does not talk about the scroll.

Comment: @macsontaylor 
I also recommend that you reduce the code that shows in the new questions, a quality question should only provide a [mcve], not its complete code, in the long term no one can help you because it will have too much code, read because it is inconvenient to have too much code in the following link: http://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchcode/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your requirement can be divided into 2 tasks:

- Detection of the keys for this we use [`Keyboard`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.core.window.html#kivy.core.window.Keyboard).
- Selection of the nodes, for this we use the [`select_node()`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.treeview.html#kivy.uix.treeview.TreeView.select_node) method of [`TreeView`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.treeview.html#module-kivy.uix.treeview) that allows us to select a specific node, [`selected_node`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.treeview.html#kivy.uix.treeview.TreeView.selected_node) that returns the currently selected node. (*You should not overwrite the select_node method, remove that from your code.*)

---

```
....
class TreeviewGroup(Popup):
    treeview = ObjectProperty(None)
    tv = ObjectProperty(None)
    #ti = ObjectProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TreeviewGroup, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.tv = TreeView(root_options=dict(text=""),
                       hide_root=False,
                       indent_level=4)
        for branch in tree:
            populate_tree_view(self.tv, None, branch)
        self.remove_widgets()
        self.treeview.add_widget(self.tv)

        self.bind(on_open=self.on_open)

    def on_open(self, *args):
        self._keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(self._keyboard_closed, self)
        self._keyboard.bind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)
        if self.tv.selected_node is None:
            self.tv.select_node(self.tv.root.nodes[0])

    def _keyboard_closed(self):
        self._keyboard.unbind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)
        self._keyboard = None

    def _on_keyboard_down(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        node = self.tv.selected_node
        _, key = keycode
        if key in ('down', 'up'):
            parent = node.parent_node
            ix = parent.nodes.index(node)
            nx = ix+1 if 'down' else ix-1
            next_node = parent.nodes[nx % len(parent.nodes)]
            self.tv.select_node(next_node)
            return True
        elif key == 'enter':
            App.get_running_app().root.name.text = node.text
            keyboard.release()
            self.dismiss()

    ...

class GroupScreen(Screen):
    name = ObjectProperty(None)
    popup = ObjectProperty(None)

    def display_groups(self, instance):
        if len(instance.text) > 0:
            if self.popup is None:
                self.popup = TreeviewGroup()
            #self.popup.filter(instance.text)
            self.popup.open()

...
```

Comment: thanks.`up` and `down` keys working perfect but when `enter` key pressed then not copied text into `TextBox`

Comment: @macsontaylor 
Have you tried it correctly? I just tried it and it works, what textbox do you mean, which is aligned with Code or with Name ?, have you removed the select_node from TreeviewGroup and GroupScreen?

Comment: there are 2 enter key in keyboard.one `enter` key is working perfect but another does not work.It's strange

Comment: @macsontaylor there is only one enter key, what keyboard do you have? Maybe the other one is the return key.

Comment: @macsontaylor print the variable `key` when you press the enter key that does not work for you.

Comment: @macsontaylor then change `elif key == 'enter':` to `elif key in ('enter', 'numpadenter'):`. It is more elegant since you do not repeat code unnecessarily.