# Python kivy on android with hardware barcode scanner

Tags: python, kivy, barcode, reader

I have a project where I need to integrate a hardware barcode scanner built into an Android Barcode scanning Device (Cipherlab). My app is built and the only part outstanding is reading the barcode. The barcodes are terminated by an enter keycode. The enter keys are being detected but the rest of the barcode does not display in the textinput which has focus.

I have tested the scanner in a text editor and it's not that. So it looks like the text is being scanned in the app as the enter keycode triggers the on_text_validate event.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

Builder.load_string('''
<MainScreen>:
    text_in: text_in
    memberStatus: memberStatus
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label: 
            id: memberStatus
        TextInput:
            id: text_in
            multiline: False
            on_text_validate:
                root.process_barcode()
''')


class MainScreen(Screen):
    def process_barcode(self):
        self.memberStatus.text = "Read Value:"+ self.text_in.text
        self.text_in.text = ""
        Clock.schedule_once(lambda *args: setattr(self.text_in, 'focus', True))

    def on_enter(self):
        self.memberStatus.text = "Text Input has focus"
        Clock.schedule_once(lambda *args: setattr(self.text_in, 'focus', True))


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(MainScreen(name="screen_main"))
        return sm


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) addressing your main problem.

Comment: @ ApuCoder - Thanks, I have updated the code with minimal functionality which runs on the Android Scanner. Code works perfectly when a keyboard is used on the device but not when the barcode read happens. It only detects the enter keycode but none of the characters

Comment: You need to bind some event(s) to keyboard. Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49595328).

Comment: @ APUCoder - After binding the events to the keyboard I still had the same issues. The barcode reader's data was still not accessible in the Kivy app. I then looked at the actual Reader config app on the scanner. Changed the setting "Data output - Keyboard Emulation" from "InputMethod" to "KeyEvent" and it all started to work as expected. Thank you for your time and effort.