How to restart a kivy window after using ESC key
How to restart a kivy window after using ESC key
I've been trying to open my kivy app a second time after closing the window (because it's a tray app).
However I run into an exception, when closing the App using the Esc key and then re-running the app.
This error doesn't happen, when I close the window by clicking the cross in the window bar instead.
Here is some code example reproducing the issue:
from time import sleep

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget


class MyApp(App):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.my_window = Widget()

    def build(self):
        return self.my_window

    def on_stop(self):
        Window.hide()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Window.top = 30
    app = MyApp()
    app.run()
    # Restart the App after one second
    sleep(1)
    Window.show()
    app.run()

When closing the first window using the esc key, the second window does not appear. Instead I receive this:
Connected to pydev debugger (build 223.8836.43)
[INFO   ] WM_MotionEventProvider <kivy.input.providers.wm_touch.WM_MotionEventProvider object at 0x0000016E2A86E790>
[INFO   ] WM_MotionEventProvider <kivy.input.providers.wm_touch.WM_MotionEventProvider object at 0x0000016E2A8816D0>
[ERROR  ] [Base        ] No event listeners have been created
[ERROR  ] [Base        ] Application will leave
python-BaseException

Is there some way to avoid this problem?
(This happens in kivy2.3.0 on python3.11 and windows11)

If its acceptable to you, you could disable the feature of the Esc key causing the program to exit as described in this post

Thanks this worked for me. I've also added the closing on esc back in, using the solution from this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/49595328/7062162

This is the full solution I went with, in case anyone else comes across this issue. I've first disabled the built-in escape as suggested by @nigh_anxiety. Then added my own method to close the window.
from time import sleep

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.config import Config

Config.set('kivy', 'exit_on_escape', '0')  # Disable the built-in feature


class MyApp(App):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.my_window = Widget()

        self._keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(self._keyboard_closed, self)
        self._keyboard.bind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)

    def _keyboard_closed(self):
        self._keyboard.unbind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)
        self._keyboard = None

    def _on_keyboard_down(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        _, key = keycode
        if key == 'escape':
            app.stop()

    def build(self):
        return self.my_window


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Window.top = 30
    app = MyApp()
    app.run()
    Window.hide()
    # Restart the App after one second
    sleep(1)
    Window.show()
    app.run()


In your code, try replacing:
Window.show()
app.run()

with:
file = sys.argv[0]
try:
    if os.path.exists(file):
        print('running 1: os.execl(', sys.executable, 'python', file)
        os.execl(sys.executable, 'python', file)
    else:
        print('running 2: os.execl(', sys.executable, 'python', os.path.join(os.getcwd(), file))
        os.execl(sys.executable, 'python', os.path.join(os.getcwd(), file))
except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)

This replaces the current process with a new python process.
Note that this ends up as an infinite loop, since there is no way to cleanly end this code.

This works for the example, but it's not really what I need, because it starts the entire script not just the app.
